# Quicker method than looping through thousands of records

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, collections

Is there a quicker way than looping through thousands of records (around 24k)?

Code:

```
For n = 0 To oCHStockItems.Count - 1

    Dim itemSellingPrice As New CH.CH_ItemSellingPrice

    With itemSellingPrice
        .StockItem = oCHStockItems(n).StockItem
        .Code = oCHStockItems(n).StockItem.Code
        .Name = oCHStockItems(n).StockItem.Name
        .ProductGroupCode = oCHStockItems(n).StockItem.ProductGroup.Code
        .CurrentSellingPrice = oCHStockItems(n).StockItem.StockItemPrices(0).Price
        .NewSellingPrice = 0D
        .LastSellingPriceDate = oCHStockItems(n).LastSellingPriceDate
        .OriginalPrice = oCHStockItems(n).OriginalPrice
        End With

    _itemSellingPrices.Add(itemSellingPrice)
Next
```

Originally I was assigning `oCHStockItems` to a `Grid` (it's actually a Sage 200 Grid) however I can't seem to find a way to reference to the field `oCHStockItems(n).StockItem.StockItemPrices(0).Price`.

[image: This is my grid]

Normally the above kind of syntax works. For example if I want to reference to the **Stock Code** it would be `StockItem.Code`.

`StockItem.StockItemPrices(0).Price` does produce a value however it doesn't show on the Grid. I've logged a ticket with Sage to see if they can help.

However I'm thinking they will come back and say that it can't be done and on that assumption I'm kind of left with looping through `oStockItems` and assigning the properties to the properties of my predefined class. So with that in mind has anyone any suggestions of speeding this kind of process up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sage got back to me with a solution:

First:

```
AddHandler dgItems.Items.ItemAdded, AddressOf Items_ItemAdded
```

Then:

```
Private Sub Items_ItemAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As Sage.Common.Controls.ListItemArgs)
    args.Item.SubItems(4).Value = oCHStockItems(args.Item.Index).StockItem.StockItemPrices(0).Price
End Sub
```

This quickly populates the item on the `Grid`.

All I have done is assign the original collection `oCHStockItems` to the `.DataSource` of the grid and the method `Items_ItemAdded` sorts the rest out.